# Dynamic configuration of MSAL 2 in Angular

Tags: angular, configuration, post-build, msal-angular

For my Angular (v12) application, I use MSAL for Authentication and I'm facing an issue on configuration.

In configuration, I have tenantId and app Id to initialize MSAL.

I cannot use the standard Angular configuration switching with `environment.ts` since it cannot be changed in a post build step.

Instead, I try to load a json file and call at app startup using APP_INITIALIZER callback as it is explained in this post : [How to initialize msal configurations using APP_INITIALIZER](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/1403)

I've modified it a bit since `MsalAngularConfiguration` doesn't exist anymore in MSAL v2.

But it's not working, a call to `MSALInstanceFactory` is done before ConfigService.init is called (by AppComponent since it depends from `MsalGuardConfiguration`).

I've tried also to pass `ConfigService` in `msalConfigFactory` function, but the parameter is undefined.

I've also tried to import in code as json, but it doesn't work since I got the values when it was built.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that i've double used my AppConfigService in providers.
I've done the same using a local factory, and it works:

```
export function EnvConfigurationFactory(httpBackend: HttpBackend) {

  return () => {
    let http = new HttpClient(httpBackend);
    return http.get('assets/configuration/environment.json')
            .toPromise()
            .then((resp) => {
              for (var key in resp) {
                environment[key] = resp[key];
              }
            })
  }
}
```

I'm using HttpBackend instead of HttpClient since an HTTP_INTERCEPTORS is configured and use the settings I try to set.
And I set directly the values of environment object with environment.json file.

Comment: am having the same issue. could you share your app.module file ?

Comment: Use the factory above in the providers section:

`  providers: [
    
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: EnvConfigurationFactory,
      deps: [HttpBackend],
      multi: true
    },
]`

Comment: I added the same. but am getting undefined when i access

Comment: export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      //  clientId: configService.getSettings("clientId"),
      //  authority: configService.getSettings("authority"),
      //  redirectUri: configService.getSettings("redirectUri")
      clientId: config.clientId,
      authority: config.authority,
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200"
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // Set to true for Internet Explorer 11
    }
  })
}

Comment: i want to store the result of promise to global so i can access it in other way place but am getting undefined

Comment: The note about the HttpBackend was the missing link for me! Thank you so much! I kept getting this circular dependency in MsalInterceptor factory when using HttpClient.